# Unknown column 'valueone' in 'field list'

Tags: php, cakephp, migration, cakephp-2.0, seed

When attempting to seed data into my database table I keep on receiving the following error: 
`[PDOException] SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'valueone' in 'field list'`

I have searched all over stackoverflow and google but I'm unable to find a solution. I have tried migrating, refactoring my class names and seeding repeatedly.

My migration file:

```
    public function change() {
        $table = $this->table('custom_values');
        $table->addColumn('valueone', 'string', [
            'default' => null,
            'limit' => 27,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('valuetwo', 'date', [
            'default' => null,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->addColumn('valuethree', 'boolean', [
            'default' => null,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->create();
    }
```

My seeder:

```
public function run() {
    $data = [
        [
            'valueone' => 'NL',
            'valuetwo' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'valuethree' => true,
        ],
    ];

    $table = $this->table('custom_values');
    $table->insert($data)
        ->save();
}
```

If only you could help me resolve this issue that would be very much appreciated. Happy coding!

Comment: try to clear cache bin/cake cache clear_all

Comment: Hi Salines. I tried but still the same error.

Comment: Please generate SQL statement from your `database` for table `custom_values` and share it here